# Export final data from numpy to excel

Tags: python, numpy

here I used panda for export my data which is located in numpy array. but there is a problem that I cant export my data and also there is a erroe that you can see below.

valueError: Must pass 2-d input

this is my main variable AccZONE=c.T and The type of that is Array Of float64, and the size Of That is (710,1,1)

Comment: Please share your code as a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it looks like the array is 3 dimensions, you need to change it to 2 dimensions, it would be nice if you could provide some code.

You can try `np.reshape(arr,(-1,1))` or `np.ravel(arr)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and can you tell me How can I change it to 2 dimensions?

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look, it looks like you’re trying to make a vector.

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark it correct @Khashayar_MO

Comment: sorry, I dont know how Can I mark correct?

Comment: @Khashayar_MO click the tick on my answer

Comment: @Khashayar_MO the tick on the left of the post next to the arrows

Comment: yes, I did it, Thanks